# How would I code a PHP search form to search my database table that contains a JSON array?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working at this most of the day, I've finally learned a little bit about `json_decode` - now I can successfully fetch specific data to the logged a logged in user.

Now I want to have the ability for people to use a PHP search from that can search my database that has the JSON Array - I want it so it searched for the $charinfo['firstname'] and $charinfo['lastname']. I hope my question makes sense. I've been researching and I haven't come across any solutions that help me (I've tried them all).

Here's the code that I have so far.... (I know, I just learned procedural PHP so that's what I am most comfortable with at the moment)

```
<form method="GET" action="person-lookup.php">
  <input type="text" name="search"/>
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
               <?php
                 if(isset($_GET['search'])){
                                            
                 $key = $_GET["search"];
                 $chars = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE 'charinfo' LIKE '%key%'";
                                                
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($chars)) {
                    $charinfo_json = $row['charinfo'];
                                        

                 $charinfo = json_decode($charinfo_json, true);

                         echo $charinfo['firstname'];
                                    }
                                }

                                    ?>
```

and the error I get when searching the form is;

`Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given`.

Comment: $chars is a *string*. First use [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (eg.) to return a mysqli_result that can be used. Then it should look something akin to `$result = mysqli_query($chars); mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`. It might be a good time to switch to the 'OO' form, which can also aid in clarity of "why" one needs the result first.

Comment: That is also prone to SQL Injection, when attempting to shove the search value directly in the SQL query string (which in this case wasn't even correctly done due to failed interpolation), of which there is a note in the above link.

Comment: There are few occasions where storing JSON data in a database is appropriate, but this is almost certainly not one of them. If you want to search your tables and update them you'll find it a whole lot easier to set up proper columns and access the data directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,  the problem is you did not use mysqli_query function

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}

....

$query =  mysqli_query($con,$chars);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $charinfo_json = $row['charinfo'];
    $charinfo = json_decode($charinfo_json, true);
    echo $charinfo['firstname'];
}
```

Comment: A good answer will include an explanation of what was changed (so that OP and any future readers aren't left with the tedious task of comparing the answer code to the question code line by line to find the difference) and, more importantly, *why* it was changed and in what way it solves the issue, so that any readers can learn from it.